# Disable ng-click

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-click

I'm trying to disable an ng-click directive.
I have this script I call in a kendo grid

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="PnIssueCell">
    <span style="white-space: normal" ng-click="vm.Drawing.ID_PN_ISSUE == dataItem.ID_PN_ISSUE || vm.HistoryPopup(vm.Drawing, true)">
        {{ dataItem.ID_PN_ISSUE }}
    </span>
</script>
```

I want that if the condition `vm.Drawing.ID_PN_ISSUE == dataItem.ID_PN_ISSUE` is true the action has to be enabled.

But something is not working correctly, in fact the row is always clickable.

Any suggestion?

thanks a lot

Comment: Can you try `vm.Drawing.ID_PN_ISSUE === dataItem.ID_PN_ISSUE`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a small correction in your code, Here I'm evaluating your expression first, if the xpression is **true**. it executes your function otherwise it doesn't.

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="PnIssueCell">
    <span style="white-space: normal" ng-click="(vm.Drawing.ID_PN_ISSUE == dataItem.ID_PN_ISSUE)?vm.HistoryPopup(vm.Drawing, true):null ">
        {{ dataItem.ID_PN_ISSUE }}
    </span>
</script>
```

Hope this helps :)

**More specific solution for your problem:**

As we discussed in comments, You want to remove the **pointer icon**(hand icon) on that element, then you can try with **button** element instead of **span**.

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="PnIssueCell">
    <button type="button" style="white-space: normal" ng-click="vm.HistoryPopup(vm.Drawing, true)" ng-disabled="!(vm.Drawing.ID_PN_ISSUE == dataItem.ID_PN_ISSUE)">
        {{ dataItem.ID_PN_ISSUE }}
    </button>
</script>
```

Now you don't need to worry about disabling **ng-click** because, here when expression is false, we are disabling the button, which means we are not allowing any click actions and at the same time, browser automatically changes **pointer** icon to **arrow**, as it's a disabled button.

Comment: Ok it perfectly works with the ternary operator. But if I want to remove the hand icon? What should I do? Because I don't want the hand icon and then if someone click nothing happens

Comment: Then the best thing you can do is, instead of using 'span', you can use 'button', and you can use the same condition with ng-disabled, so when the expression is true then button will be enabled, otherwise it'll be disabled. So if button is disabled, automatically browser removes the hand icon. then you don't even need to worry about disabling ng-click, because browser automatically disables all action on that button.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `&&` instead of `||` for your example to work.
Or use a ternary operator (`condition ? action : null`)

Otherwise, if you do it often, you may want to create a directive to disable the click event and add other features (like toggling some CSS class to show that the action is disabled).

Something like this.

HTML Code

```
<span disable-if="vm.Drawing.ID_PN_ISSUE != dataItem.ID_PN_ISSUE"
      ng-click="vm.HistoryPopup(vm.Drawing, true)">
    {{ dataItem.ID_PN_ISSUE }}
</span>
```

Javscript Code

```
.directive('disableIf', function() {
    var inhibitHandler = function(event) {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    };

    return {
        retrict: 'A',
        priority: 100,
        scope: { disableIf: "=" },
        link: function($scope, element) {
            $scope.$watch('disableIf', function(disable) {
                if (disable) {
                    element.addClass('disabled')
                    element.on('click', inhibitHandler);
                }
                else {
                    element.removeClass('disabled')
                    element.off('click', inhibitHandler);
                }

                // you may want to add a handler to remove the
                // event listener when the scope is destroyed
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Ok it perfectly works with the ternary operator.
But if I want to remove the hand icon? What should I do?

Comment: Either use ng-style with another ternary operator, or implement a directive like the provided example that does that for you

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just wrap your `HistoryPopup` function and `vm.Drawing.ID_PN_ISSUE == dataItem.ID_PN_ISSUE` condition in a separate function? If the condition is true, then invoke the function.

View layer (i.e. your html template) should not have or include any logic from controllers.